# What does "wisdom that is so often loudly preached" mean in the Parable of the King and the Maiden?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, soren-kierkegaard

In the first paragraph of "The Parable of the King and the Maiden":

> Suppose there was a king who loved a humble maiden and whose heart was unaffected by the wisdom that is so often loudly preached.

What does "*wisdom that is so often loudly preached*" mean here? Does it mean the king didn't listen to other people who thought he's wrong about the girl?